# Why do C# 12 primary constructors execute in opposite order?

Tags: c#, constructor, .net-8.0, c#-12.0, primary-constructor

Why do [primary constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/primary-constructors) in C# 12 do execute in opposite order?

That's kind of a *breaking change* to say the least...

Example:

```
namespace Whatever;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTestTemp
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() // PASS // is expected, 1st is 1, 2nd is 2
    {
        using var stream = new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });

        var classicDerived = new ClassicDerived(stream);

        Console.WriteLine(classicDerived.Value1);
        Console.WriteLine(classicDerived.Value2);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, classicDerived.Value1);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, classicDerived.Value2);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2() // FAIL // is opposite, 1st is 2, 2nd is 1
    {
        using var stream = new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });

        var primaryDerived = new PrimaryDerived(stream);

        Console.WriteLine(primaryDerived.Value1);
        Console.WriteLine(primaryDerived.Value2);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, primaryDerived.Value1);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, primaryDerived.Value2);
    }
}
```

Classic constructor:

```
public class ClassicBase
{
    public readonly int Value1;

    protected ClassicBase(Stream stream)
    {
        Value1 = stream.ReadByte();
    }
}

public class ClassicDerived : ClassicBase
{
    public readonly int Value2;

    public ClassicDerived(Stream stream) : base(stream)
    {
        Value2 = stream.ReadByte();
    }
}
```

Primary constructor:

```
public class PrimaryBase(Stream stream)
{
    public readonly int Value1 = stream.ReadByte();
}

public class PrimaryDerived(Stream stream) : PrimaryBase(stream)
{
    public readonly int Value2 = stream.ReadByte();
}
```

1st test outcome:

```
 TestMethod1
   Source: UnitTestTemp.cs line 7
   Duration: 4 ms

  Standard Output: 
1
2
```

2nd test outcome:

```
 TestMethod2
   Source: UnitTestTemp.cs line 21
   Duration: 26 ms

  Message: 
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1>. Actual:<2>. 

  Stack Trace: 
UnitTestTemp.TestMethod2() line 30
RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

  Standard Output: 
2
1
```

As you can see, it's a bit problematic if for instance you use a stream from within constructors.

**Question:**

Is there another way to address that beside reverting to classic constructors?

(was thinking of maybe something like [SetsRequiredMembers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.setsrequiredmembersattribute) for the new [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) modifier)

Comment: Sounds like that's according to the [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/primary-constructors#semantics): *Primary Constructor will do the following sequence of operations: parameter values are stored in capture fields, if any, instance initializers are executed, base constructor initializer is called*. I don't see any easy way to work this around and frankly, I'd fall back to classic constructors.

Comment: Note that without Primary Constructors, the field initializers also run starting with the ones in the most-derived class. That's not a quirk specific to Primary Constructors, but they make it more likely to matter, since without them you'd typically do side effects in the constructor rather than in initializers.

Comment: Yes... I should have read better, it's marked as **experimental**.

Comment: The spec linked by @WiktorZychla in his comment here, also lists the following as drawback: _As proposed, execution order semantics are subtly different from within ordinary constructors, delaying member initializers to after the base calls. This could probably be remedied, but at the cost of some of the extension proposals (notably "primary constructor bodies")._ In fact, it is not possible to write a type that behaves exactly like `PrimaryDerived` with a "classical" explicit constructor. Note that `PrimaryDerived` as above does _not_ **capture** its constructor argument and make it a field.

Comment: Both answers are equally good, not sure which to pick!

Comment: Not an answer, but could not resist to advise against "doing work" (read from stream in the example) in the constructor, primary or classic.

Comment: @Arthur What would you do then? Wrap the reading in a `Create` method?

Comment: @aybe Difficult to say without knowing more about the context.  My naïve thought is to have the caller that manages the Stream do the read, then the constructor takes an int.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

Your primary ctor case is using field initialization and from the [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields):

> **Fields are initialized immediately before the constructor for the object instance is called**. If the constructor assigns the value of a field, it overwrites any value given during field declaration.

So all fields initialization happens before the constructors being called resulting in first derived class fields initialized and then the base (I assume this happens due to ability to call overloaded methods in the base ctor and those overloaded methods might use some initialized fields - see for example [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEBMBGAWACgYBTAdwAIARU5KAN1IBMBhAGwgGcuAKASgDcxYlgDMlXJQBC3Uh25diAb2IBIcTLkKeA9aqJq11APYDhhgL4jDmhlGQJUEdpIAsNM/2XWiv0RJStPRMbJw8lCBaXPLhSkQGGhLIpBDMJjDsAJ6UsAiUAGouqKQ4lAC8lG44Fkk0dIwsOnz8+upqRewlZZUA7P21vnUmTMj0zKTunnqGiRp4AJy8nd1C6r6WQA=)).

And from the [Primary constructors specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/primary-constructors#semantics):

> Primary Constructor will do the following sequence of operations:
>
> - Parameter values are stored in capture fields, if any.
> - Instance initializers are executed
> - Base constructor initializer is called

**Details**

If you check the [decompilation of your classes with primary ctors](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBAGABAlAOgEkB5Abk0wQGZ8lcAFAJykmYE8AhCAZwFMAFAGUALs34QwuXuMlgAlJgDemXOvx0JEACYB7GABsOuWKNwA1CIYCu/FLgC8MuVMIAlSTq4dRQhZQYAL5UWHTITKzsHAAi/KwAbvw6Iq7SstqKuCCRbBCcPAKCGfJKGKoYGpq42vpGJmaW1nYMziVunro+foIBmEFAA==) you will see something like the following:

```
public class PrimaryBase
{
    public readonly int Value1 = stream.ReadByte();

    public PrimaryBase(Stream stream)
    {
    }
}

public class PrimaryDerived : PrimaryBase
{
    public readonly int Value2 = stream.ReadByte();

    public PrimaryDerived(Stream stream)
        : base(stream)
    {
    }
}
```

Hence the fields will be initialized before ctor call and subsequently before initialization of base class.

And the [following IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYCMBYAKAwAYACDHAOgEkB5AbkMIwGZytSAFAJykm4CeAIQgBnAKYAKAMoJu4iGFKi5CsAEpCAb0Kk95NvIgATAPYwUA0rASkAahBQBXcTlIBeZasWUASguMhAQQpdUYCAF8mIjZsLl5+AQARcV4AN3FjGW8lFSMNUhB4vghBEQlJPLVNAh0CfQNSIzMLKxt7RxcOTyqffxMgkMkwwgigA==) for ctors:

Derived:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor (
class [System.Runtime]System.IO.Stream 'stream'
    ) cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute::.ctor(uint8) = (
        01 00 01 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20b1
        // Code size 20 (0x14)
        .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldarg.1
    IL_0002: callvirt instance int32 [System.Runtime]System.IO.Stream::ReadByte()
    IL_0007: stfld int32 PrimaryDerived::Value2
    IL_000c: ldarg.0
    IL_000d: ldarg.1
    IL_000e: call instance void PrimaryBase::.ctor(class [System.Runtime]System.IO.Stream)
    IL_0013: ret
} // end of method PrimaryDerived::.ctor
```

Base:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor (
class [System.Runtime]System.IO.Stream 'stream'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x209d
    // Code size 19 (0x13)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldarg.1
    IL_0002: callvirt instance int32 [System.Runtime]System.IO.Stream::ReadByte()
    IL_0007: stfld int32 PrimaryBase::Value1
    IL_000c: ldarg.0
    IL_000d: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0012: ret
} // end of method PrimaryBase::.ctor
```

So basically from IL (and "lower") standpoint of view the derived class ctor will actually always be called first, it will initialize the derived fields, call the base ctor (which in it's turn will initialize fields and call code defined in C# base class ctor) and then call code defined in C# derived class ctor.

The minimal reproducible example to compare the behaviours can be arguably simplified to something like the following:

```
public static class Helper
{
    private static int Counter = 0;

    public static int GetValue(string callerName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{callerName}: {Counter}");
        return Counter++;
    }
}
```

```cs
// "Classic" 
public class ClassicCtorBase
{
    public readonly int Value1;
    protected ClassicCtorBase() => Value1 = Helper.GetValue(nameof(ClassicCtorBase));
}

public class ClassicCtorDerived : ClassicCtorBase
{
    public readonly int Value2;
    public ClassicCtorDerived() => Value2 = Helper.GetValue(nameof(ClassicCtorDerived));
}

// Classic witout ctor but with fields initialization
public class ClassicFieldInitBase
{
    public readonly int Value1 = Helper.GetValue(nameof(ClassicFieldInitBase));
}

public class ClassicFieldInitDerived : ClassicFieldInitBase
{
    public readonly int Value2 = Helper.GetValue(nameof(ClassicFieldInitDerived));
}

// Primary ctor
public class PrimaryBase(int i = 1)
{
    public readonly int Value1 = Helper.GetValue(nameof(PrimaryBase));
}

public class PrimaryDerived(int i = 2) : PrimaryBase(i)
{
    public readonly int Value2 = Helper.GetValue(nameof(PrimaryDerived));
}
```

And execution:

```
new ClassicCtorDerived();
new ClassicFieldInitDerived();
new PrimaryDerived();
```

Which leads to the following output:

```
ClassicCtorBase: 0
ClassicCtorDerived: 1
ClassicFieldInitDerived: 2
ClassicFieldInitBase: 3
PrimaryDerived: 4
PrimaryBase: 5
```

As you can see both "classic" with fields init and primary ctor classes have the same order.

[Demo @sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

Comment: The short story is that there is a difference, because code is moved from constructor code to initializer code, which changes the order of execution.

Comment: @PoulBak yes, this is summed up in the TL;DR )

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are comparing apples with oranges.

In the Classic classes you are initializing in the constructor, while in the Primary classes you are initializing in initializers. And the order of execution of constructors and initializers is indeed different. This has nothing to do with primary constructors.

You get the reverse order if you are using initializers without primary constructors being involved.

I have a sightly different setup. This is my helper class:

```cs
static class Values
{
    private static int n = 0;

    public static int GetNext(string name)
    {
        n++;
        Console.WriteLine($"{name}: {n}");
        return n;
    }
}
```

The classic class hierarchy:

```cs
public class ClassicBase
{
    public readonly int InitValue1 = Values.GetNext(nameof(InitValue1));
    public readonly int CtorValue1;

    public ClassicBase()
    {
        CtorValue1 = Values.GetNext(nameof(CtorValue1));
    }
}

public class ClassicDerived : ClassicBase
{
    public readonly int InitValue2 = Values.GetNext(nameof(InitValue2));
    public readonly int CtorValue2;

    public ClassicDerived()
    {
        CtorValue2 = Values.GetNext(nameof(CtorValue2));
    }
}
```

The test

```
_ = new ClassicDerived();
Console.ReadKey();
```

It prints:

```
InitValue2: 1
InitValue1: 2
CtorValue1: 3
CtorValue2: 4
```

See also:

- [In what order do things happen?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/462106/in-what-order-do-things-happen) (especially
  Timon Yang-MSFT's answer)
- [Why Do Initializers Run In The Opposite Order As Constructors? Part One (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one/)
- [Why Do Initializers Run In The Opposite Order As Constructors? Part Two (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two/)

Comment: This still does not make it clear, to me at least, how everything goes in the example from the original question marked as "Primary constructor". By reflection, it seems the constructor parameter `Stream stream` does _not_ give rise to an invisible (compiler-generated) field in his class. According to the links you provide, field initializers should run _before_ any constructors. But the expression the initializers assign, `stream.ReadByte();`, makes no sense before any constructors. The example in your answer avoids the new feature.

Comment: (continued) Even if the asker "compares apples with oranges", which may be true, it could still be interesting to understand how it _does_ work with the new feature in the asker's `new PrimaryDerived(stream)` case. EDIT: Is there a way to write "classical code", i.e. without primary constructors, that behaves the same as the "modern" code in the asker's example?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen _"But the expression the initializers assign, stream.ReadByte();, makes no sense before any constructors."_ - if you look at IL it kind of does. Actually in the IL you always call the derived class ctor first which will invoke it's own initializers, then call the base ctor then call the code defined in the derived one. See it in my answer (partially).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen and in this and in this [sharplab decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYCMBYAKBgFMB3AAgBFiAnKAN2IBMBhFCAZw4AoBKAbkKEMAZnLZyAIU7E2nDoQDehAJCipMuVz6rlBFSsoB7PoP0BfIfvX0oNBAFcIKcQBYqJ3ossEfwsRLUdIys7FzkIBocsmEKBHpqYjTEEExGMCgAnuSwCOQAas4OxFjkALzkrlhmiVS0DMxaPLy6hOTtHe0YOACc3ABE/QKqKoUoxaUVAOwzNT61Row0dEzEbh46+glqvdxjE8MWhOZAA==)